# How to get live location from Facebook messenger api chatbots

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm building a Facebook messanger bot and I'm trying to get users live location but the "get location" button available on the api only gets the current (longitude, latitude)
Is there a way to get the live location after one permission?
And if not will it be in the soon feature please?
Thanks you.

Comment: The user need to send you their location. You can't track them.

Comment: It's for a taxi app can't i get a live location after they accept a permission once?

Comment: I've built a bot on facebook and as far as I know the location pin is the only way to get a users location. As a bot is just a page talking back automatically you would need to share your permanent location with that page, which may have a considerable number of ramifications for other kinds of pages.

Comment: Correct. The user manually need to send the location when you need it

Comment: I need it live ! It's a taxi app! Is there any other solution?

Comment: Make an Android or iOS app that people installs. There is no way to do it in a messenger bot.